# transform variables and add to dataframe

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I would like to log transform several variables in a dataframe and to then add the transformed variables to the dataframe as new variables named using 'logoldname'. What are the best ways of doing these in R efficiently? Thank you!

```
data("mtcars")
head(mtcars)

#Log transform - maunally
mtcars$logdisp <- log(mtcars$disp)
mtcars$loghp <- log(mtcars$hp)
mtcars$logwt <- log(mtcars$wt)
mtcars$logqsec <- log(mtcars$qsec)
```

Comment: Could downvoters please read the accepted answer to the Meta [Downvoting of new user questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3515/downvoting-of-new-user-questions/3524)? Moreover, this new user describes the problem and uses an example dataset, something many others don't do and are not downvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why the downvotes; I think the question is perfectly fine, and a comment with an explanation how OP could've improved his question would have helped.

That aside, here is a `tidyverse` solution:

```
# These are the columns with entries you'd like to log-transform
ss <- c("disp", "hp", "wt", "qsec")

mtcars %>%
    mutate_at(vars(one_of(ss)), funs(log = log(.))) %>%
    rename_at(vars(contains("_log")), funs(paste0("log_", gsub("_log", "", .)))) %>%
    select(contains("log_"))
#   log_disp   log_hp    log_wt log_qsec
#1  5.075174 4.700480 0.9631743 2.800933
#2  5.075174 4.700480 1.0560527 2.834389
#3  4.682131 4.532599 0.8415672 2.923699
#4  5.552960 4.700480 1.1678274 2.967333
#5  5.886104 5.164786 1.2354715 2.834389
#6  5.416100 4.653960 1.2412686 3.006672
```

Explanation: `mutate_at` selects columns that match `ss` and applies a `log` transformation. This generates new columns, named e.g. `"disp_log"`, `"hp_log"` and so on. We then rename those columns into `log_disp`, `log_hp`, etc., and select only the log-transformed columns in the final step.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses base R only, and I believe is simpler than the `tidyverse` solution. I will use the vector `ss` in that solution, by @Maurits Evers.

```
data("mtcars")

ss <- c("disp", "hp", "wt", "qsec")
logs <- sapply(mtcars[ss], log)
colnames(logs) <- paste("log", ss, sep = "_")
result <- cbind(mtcars, logs)
head(result)
#                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb log_disp
#Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 5.075174
#Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 5.075174
#Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 4.682131
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 5.552960
#Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 5.886104
#Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 5.416100
#                    log_hp    log_wt log_qsec
#Mazda RX4         4.700480 0.9631743 2.800933
#Mazda RX4 Wag     4.700480 1.0560527 2.834389
#Datsun 710        4.532599 0.8415672 2.923699
#Hornet 4 Drive    4.700480 1.1678274 2.967333
#Hornet Sportabout 5.164786 1.2354715 2.834389
#Valiant           4.653960 1.2412686 3.006672
```

If you don't want to `cbind` the logs with the original dataframe, you can coerce the `matrix` produced by `sapply` to `data.frame`:

```
result <- as.data.frame(logs)
```

And maybe a final clean up, `rm(logs)`.